# RQuantLib install on OSX fails to detect QuantLib installation

Tags: r, osx-yosemite, quantlib

I'm trying to install RQuantLib on a MAC (OSX 10.10) with an up to date version of R (3.2.2).  I understand the RQuantLib requires QuantLib and have compiled and installed it, apparently successfully.  At least when I type

```
quantlib-config --version
```

at the command prompt, I get back

```
1.6.2
```

However, when I attempt to install RQuantLib through the GUI (Package Installer), I get the following:

```
* installing *source* package ‘RQuantLib’ ...
** package ‘RQuantLib’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for R... yes
checking for quantlib-config... no
configure: error: Please install QuantLib before trying to build RQuantLib.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RQuantLib’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/k7/r94by_b92ydgxg817p9nt_2r0000gn/T/RtmpUjAuhq/downloaded_packages’
* removing ‘/Users/edward/Library/R/3.2/library/RQuantLib’
```

It looks like the check that's failing is on line 70 of the configure.ac file (
https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rquantlib/blob/master/configure.ac), but I don't know how to take the investigation further.

Any suggestions as to how to get this installation working will be gratefully received.

******** UPDATE ****
OK.  I have found a solution to this. 
quantlib-config is in /opt/local/bin and I created a sym link for it in /usr/local/bin.

RQuantLib compile and installation then proceeded.

Don't really understand how these various directories work but, anyway, I am up an running.

Comment: Can you share how you solved this issue?